# What is the equivalent method of ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync in Azure.Data.Tables?

Tags: azure-sdk-.net, azure.data.tables

What is the equivalent method of ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync in Azure.Data.Tables?

Recently Microsoft azure sdk deprecated Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table package and recommended to use Azure.Data.Tables package.

But, I couldn't find equivalent ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync method in Azure.Data.Tables package.

**Current code using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table package below:**

```
var srcTableName = "TestTable";
var tableBatchResults = new List<TableBatchResult>();
CloudTable srcCloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(srcTableName);
var tableContinuationToken = new TableContinuationToken();
do
{
     var entities = new List<T>();

     var segment = await srcCloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<T>(tableQuery, tableContinuationToken);

     entities.AddRange(segment.Results);

}while (tableContinuationToken != null);
```

How to convert this code with Azure.Data.Tables package.

Comment: What is the `framework` and `version` you are using ?

Comment: @Harshitha: We are using .Net framework 4.8.1 and Azure.Data.Tables 12.7.1